# Plagiarism of my work

Tags: journals, plagiarism

My classmate (now a lecturer at Imo State University, Owerri, Nigeria) published my entire masters thesis’ work in an internal journal (IOSR Journal of Computer Engineering (IOSR-JCE)) without my knowledge and didn’t reference me in any way. How do I go about reporting this for the work to be retracted?

Comment: I would suggest not to name the school and journal because this could very well allow for the identification of said colleague. I think the normal procedure would be to contact the journal's editor for a retraction of the article

Comment: There's a possibility that the journal is a scam journal, in which case you could contact your own university and ask them for possible routes of actions. You want a formal process in place which takes you out of the equation and transforms it into an institutional issue - you do not want to fight this alone. I assume you already have your degree?

Comment: @Bort maybe OP's intention is that the colleague be identified.

Comment: @CapeCode that might be, but it should not. OP is entitled to his opinion on this matter, but there is the benefit of doubt for the other person involved. However this might turn out, publicly accusing somebody of something might constitute libel.

Answer (score 7):

I handled three cases of Plagiarism so far. The fastest way is to write an email to editor-in-chief of the journal and provide some documents showing that this is your work. For example, you can sent your master thesis and specify the similar parts. For me, in all cases, the editor-in-chief quickly removed the paper because they are responsible for the reputation of the journal. In case this doesn't work, then you can ask your university to handle this, but the procedure would be much longer.